# Using Say command on a breakpoint in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode and would like to set a breakpoint that speaks an NSString from my code. What I am doing is setting the breakpoint, then editing it. I add a "Shell Command" action. The first argument is `say` and the second argument is where i'm having trouble.

```
 NSString *myString = @"This is a test";
```

If I put `@myString@` as the second argument, it reads out the memory address. ex. 0x0b4be130

If I try `@[myString UTF8String]`, it gives me a another memory address.

If I dereference myString, `@*[myString UTF8String]@`, it only gives me the first character of the string.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LLDB actually has an inbuilt Python interpreter, with the entire LLDB library exposed to it. You can access this with the `script` debugger command. With this, we can more easily grab a string representation of a variable in the frame, and send it to the OS say command. Add a debugger action:

```
script os.system("say " + lldb.frame.GetValueForVariablePath("myVariable").description)
```

to achieve what you want. You can even wrap up Python scripts as new LLDB "commands", so you can create a debugger command called `say` that explicitly says the underlying objects description; have a look at http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html for an introduction on setting these type of scripts up.